# jquery html simple to do list

Tags: jquery, html

Coding some simple to do list but I cant figure out whats the problem in my code. 
Can someone figure it out? Thanks.
Here's the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add").click(function() {

    var newListItem = $("#addtolist").val();
    if (newListItem.length > 0) {
      $("#todolist").append("<li> + newListItem + </li>");
      $("#addtolist").val(" ");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>To Do List jQuery</h1>

<ul id="todolist">
</ul>

<br>
<input type="text" id="addtolist" placeholder="Type">
<button id="add">Add</button>
```

Comment: append("<li>" + newListItem + "</li>");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not creating thing the element properly.

```
 $("#todolist").append("<li>" + newListItem + "</li>");
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add").click(function() {

    var newListItem = $("#addtolist").val();
    if (newListItem.length > 0) {
      $("#todolist").append("<li>" + newListItem + "</li>");
      $("#addtolist").val(" ");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>To Do List jQuery</h1>

<ul id="todolist">
</ul>

<br>
<input type="text" id="addtolist" placeholder="Type">
<button id="add">Add</button>
```

Comment: Free rep on a poor question - why not vote to close due to typo?

Comment: @mplungjan, I have voted to delete

Answer (score 2):

This line should be like this:

```
$("#todolist").append("<li>" + newListItem + "</li>");
```

Comment: Free rep on a poor question